# Ericsson MiniPCI (USB) 3G modem unregisters after boot

Tags: usb, udev, modem

I have an internal Ericsson F3507g 3G modem (MiniPCI slot but USB connection) which gets intialised at boot but is deregistered immediately after - from dmesg:

```
[    1.366454] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.280333] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bdb, idProduct=1900
[    2.280336] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.280339] usb 2-1.4: Product: Ericsson F3507g Mobile Broadband Minicard Composite Device
[    2.280341] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Ericsson
[    2.280343] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 3541530231641440
[    8.233769] cdc_acm 2-1.4:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[    8.243124] cdc_acm 2-1.4:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[    8.243540] cdc_acm 2-1.4:1.9: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[    8.243927] cdc_wdm 2-1.4:1.5: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[    8.243981] cdc_wdm 2-1.4:1.6: cdc-wdm1: USB WDM device
[    8.842436] cdc_wdm 2-1.4:1.5: wdm_int_callback - 0 bytes
[    8.843427] cdc_wdm 2-1.4:1.6: wdm_int_callback - 0 bytes
[    8.960485] cdc_ether 2-1.4:1.7 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:80:37:ec:02:00
[    8.963595] cdc_ether 2-1.4:1.7 wwp0s29u1u4i7: renamed from wwan0
[   14.202197] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   14.210587] cdc_ether 2-1.4:1.7 wwp0s29u1u4i7: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4, Mobile Broadband Network Device
```

The device is not listed by lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And ModemManager complains:

```
Oct 06 23:39:06 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  Modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4' successfully created
Oct 06 23:39:06 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0': not supported by any plugin
Oct 06 23:39:06 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (tty/ttyACM1): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (usbmisc/cdc-wdm0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <warn>  Modem couldn't be initialized: couldn't load current capabilities: Failed to determine modem capabilities.
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (usbmisc/cdc-wdm1): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (tty/ttyACM0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (net/wwp0s29u1u4i7): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
Oct 06 23:38:54 thinkpad ModemManager[978]: <info>  (tty/ttyACM2): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
```

The CDC modules are not loaded:

```
cdc_ether              16384  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
cdc_wdm                20480  0
cdc_acm                36864  0
```

And the device is not shown in rfkill list:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have spent a handful of hours trying to figure this out on my own but I'm not getting anywhere. The same modem used to work in a different laptop with an earlier kernel. I have found a few tantalising clues around the net, but no suggestion of how to solve the problem, for example:

[Ericsson F3507g (0bdb:1900) - does not display in NetworkManager, tho USB ACM devices are registered](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/363812)

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions which may help resolve this. Perhaps it is a udev issue?

**Edit:** As requested, the output from `# udevadm test /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4`

```
calling: test
version 229
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          229
file size:         7043518 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1757550 bytes
nodes              5285888 bytes
Load module index
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Skipping overridden file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules.
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-crda.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-ifplugd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gpsd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libfreenect0.5.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-virtualbox-dkms.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-virtualbox.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-persistent-storage-android.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-xorg-synaptics-quirks.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xorg-vmmouse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-adb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-debian-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-udev-acl.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-biosdevname.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-power-switch-proliant.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-cinterion-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-mtk-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-telit-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/84-nm-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-keyboard-configuration.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-nm-unmanaged.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 32372 bytes strings
22880 strings (189561 bytes), 19581 de-duplicated (160489 bytes), 3300 trie nodes used
unable to open device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Comment: Could run `udevadm monitor` then plug the modem, add its output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I can do that; it's an internal modem that cannot easily be plugged while the machine is running. Unless there is a way to force plug/unplug via the command line?

Comment: I don't know any but could you add  output of `udevadm test /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to ponder this, I have updated the question with the requested output (run as root).

Comment: Could rerun same command for correct device name (take it from dmesg). May be the device change name on each boot. see that error `unable to open device` in the output.